# How to create a delete stored procedure making sure it cannot be deleted when it has affiliated records in another table?

Tags: oracle, join, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I have tables

- supplier( supplier_id (pk), name, address) supplier_invoice( supp_invoice-id(pk), balance)
- supplier_product (supp_prod_id(pk), Supplier_id(fk), product_id(fk), supp_invoice_id(fk))

I am trying to execute a delete procedure:

```
set serveroutput on;
create or replace
procedure delete_supp
(d_supplier_id int)
is
v_count  int;
begin
select count(*) into v_count from supplier_product where d_supplier_id=supplier_id;
    if v_count > 0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Supplier cannot be deleted because there is an existing invoice in the system');
    else    
begin
delete from supplier where supplier_id=d_supplier_id;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleted '  || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' Rows.'); 
commit;
  end;
end if;
    Exception
when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('Delete failed');          
end;
/
```

This procedure works but rather than checking if the record exists in supplier_product, I want to make sure a supplier cannot be deleted if he has open invoice in the supplier_invoice table. I tried with looping in supplier_invoice table but couldn't make it to work.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. However, you shouldn't delete any master record, move to an archive table with related data (of supplier invoices).

Comment: the only related table for supplier invoice is the supplier_product table. But i am treating that table as a purchase table where basically all the purchases are recorded. the only benefit of the purchase table is whenever a purchase is made, it will update the Inventory table and maintain the total count for the product. But I have the Supplier_invoice that will be handled against payment made. Thus, I was trying to execute a proc that allows me to delete a supplier if and only if now associated invoice is found.

Comment: `SELECT 1 from supplier s,supplier_product sp,supplier_invoice si where   s.supplier_id=sp.supplier_id and sp.supp_invoice_id=si.supp_invoice_id;` if this query returns any value then don't delete ,if not then delete ....i think this will solve your problem

Comment: @pragya: Unless the user of the system wishes to not have any trace of supplier once there isn't an associated invoice, one shouldn't delete the master record. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

Small change to your delete statement

```
DELETE FROM supplier
WHERE  supplier_id = d_supplier_id
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   supplier_product,
                              supplier_invoice
                       WHERE  supp_invoice_id = supp_invoice_id
                              AND supplier_id = d_supplier_id); 

IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
   RAISE Invoice_exists_exception;
END IF;
```

and this will ensure that supplier records will be deleted only if no records with the same supplier_id & the linked invoice id exists in the supplier_product table.

Of course, if the FKs are set up (as you mention) - then it should raise an exception when you're trying to delete..

---

Update: I used SQLFiddle to build a [sample schema/data to show this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8a3b/23):

If you have Foreign keys set up, you'll run into a ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated exception which you can trap & handle appropriately.